# How to play and download audio from database in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, audio, download, playback

please help me to fix the problem... This is my code to play and download audio from database. i am a newbie in coding.. so i don't have any knowledge to do the javascript part.. the audios are in database.. so i dont know how to get id

```
<table  id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">

     <thead>
    <th id="wid2"> Recording Id </th>
    <th id="wid1"> Unique Id</th>
    <th id="wid1"> Phone Number</th>
    <th id="wid1"> Date Time</th>
    <th id="wid1">Call Type</th>
    <th id="wid1"> Extension</th>
   <th id="wid1">Recordings</th>
</thead>
    <tbody>

<tr>
  @foreach($records as $record)
  <td id="wid2">{{$record->recording_id}}</td>
   <td id="wid2">{{$record->uniqueid}}</td>
  <td id="wid1">{{$record->phone_number}}</td>
    <td id="wid1">{{$record->datetime}}</td>
    <td id="wid1">{{$record->call_type}}</td>
    <td id="wid1">{{$record->extension}}</td> 
    <td id="wid1"><a class="btn btn-primary" id="next" href="/mp3/{{$record->recording_filename}}" 
      onclick="return playAudio();">Play</a>
      <a class="btn btn-success" id="" href="/mp3/{{$record->recording_filename}}" 
    >Donload</a>
      </td>
</tr>
    @endforeach
 </tbody>
</table>


//script for this

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById('next'); 
//alert(x);
function playAudio() {
x.play(); 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is you can use HTML `<audio>` tag.

```
  <audio controls>
  <source src="/mp3/{{$record->recording_filename}}" type="audio/mpeg"> 
  </audio>
```

It will give option for `Play/Pause` and `Download`

For download try this

```
  <a class="btn btn-success" href="/mp3/{{$record->recording_filename}}" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: Thank you dear... let me try this first

Comment: @AparnnaArun how you want to play audio then?

Comment: i have buttons play and download while clicking the corresponding buttons i need to play and download... i tried what you said and its working also.. but i need to get all the recordings from my db.

Comment: @AparnnaArun I guess you are getting urls from DB, and then you can download it, what is the problem now?

Comment: Deshmukh....i have two buttons and i wand to play my recordings from my db

Comment: @AparnnaArun you fetch recording urls from DB and those will get played, no idea how you can play recording from db.

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary" id="next" href="/mp3/{{$record->recording_filename}}" 
      onclick="playAudio();">Play<audio id="myAudio"><source src="/mp3/{{$record->recording_filename}}.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio></a>&nbsp;
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="next" href="#" 
      onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause<audio id="myAudio"><source src="/mp3/{{$record->recording_filename}}.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio></a>
<a class="btn btn-success"  href="/mp3/{{$record->recording_filename}}" download="'/mp3/{{$record->recording_filename}}.mp3'">Donload</a>

Comment: The problem is while playing the audio the same audio is plying for all the recordings.. and i was not able to download the audio file

Comment: If this answer has helped you please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark. That'd be helpful :)